# Public API how to discriminate authenticated user vs anonymous user

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda

Suppose I have an AWS Lambda and a related API Gateway endpoint API (e.g. `/user/{userid}/activities`).

This API can be invoked from both authenticated and unauthenticated users, and based on this, acts differently.

Authenticated users are users that owns a valid JWT. Unauthenticated users, haven't a JWT or their JWT is expired or it's invalid.

This JWT is validated by a Custom Authorizer who make validation based on token's signature public key and other parameters (expire date, issuer and so on).

The lambda related to `/user/{userid}/activities` needs to know if the custom authorizer had validated (or not) the related call and so can choose what behaviour should be used.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you use aws Cognito? if so there is support for authenticated and unauthenticated identities where for both a token is issued

Answer (score 0):

Approach depends on the way you distinguish anonymous and authenticated users.

Given that you want to identify anonymous users when no authorization header is specified, AWS APIGateway authorizers will always deny access since the header is missing.

You could consider following options:

1. Always use a token (for both anonymous/authenticated users).
2. Move authorization logic to a lambda wrapper (so you won't be using custom authorizer for these endpoints).
3. Proxy through a router so you get an opportunity to add authorization header if missing (with this no client changes, server add a predefined token for anonymous users).

Either way you will need to change the endpoint signature to something like: `/user/activities` and infer userId from the context, context can be updated with a proper userId post verification by the authorizer.